# How to make animation of aircraft trajectory during flight in Matlab 2015b?

Tags: matlab, animation

I have a flying aircraft in Matlab.
I want to make animation of its trajectory during flight like it is leaving trace behind.
I tried to use `animatedline` function if Matlab, but I'm just stuck here. My function just displays only сoordinate axes and nothing more.

Coordinates of aircraft are entering during flight from Simulink model.
Please, help me!

```
function trajectory(uu)
    pn       = uu(1);       % inertial North position
    pe       = uu(2);       % inertial East position
    pd       = uu(3);       % inertial Down position
    t        = uu(4);       % time

  if t==0,
    figure(10), clf
    S = 1500;
    view(0,90)
    axis([-S,S,-S,S,-.1,  S]);
    grid on      
    drawnow
  else
    h = animatedline;
    x=pe, y=pn; z=-pd;
    addpoints (h, x, y, z);
    drawnow
end
```

Comment: In the function, you are just plotting one point:  Is `uu` a 2D array, or just 1x4? Also you recreate the animated line handle before adding points, so put it where you create the figure, I think. I'm not familiar with that function, but maybe [comet3](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/comet3.html) will work for you.

Comment: `uu` is just 1x4. When I put h = `animatedline;` where I create the figure I get **Undefined function or variable 'h'.**  I'm not sure how to make it possible with `comet3` because `comet3` only plot in advance known line, my trajectory is unknown because coordinates are entering during flight.

Comment: So to find the handle, `h`, you can use `h = findobj(figure(10),'Type','AnimatedLine')` where `h = animatedline;` is currently. Though if you are doing it in simulink, there may be better ways, I don't know too much about that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to plot using the handle `h`, but it gets destroyed at the end of the function call. I propose the following solution,

```
% Function
function trajectory(uu, hLine)

pn       = uu(1);       % inertial North position
pe       = uu(2);       % inertial East position
pd       = uu(3);       % inertial Down position

x = pe; y = pn; z = -pd;
addpoints (hLine, x, y, z);
drawnow
end
```

---

```
% script
figure(10);
S = 1500;
view(0,90)
axis([-S, S, -S, S, -.1, S]);
grid on   

lineHandle = animatedline('Color','r','LineWidth',3);

for i = 1:nPoints
   % replace this with your value
   currentValue = 1000*rand(1, 4);
   trajectory(currentValue, lineHandle);
end
```

Comment: thank you, but trajectory is unknown in advance, it's entering from Simulink model, and it can change depending on flight condition.

Comment: @user8053696, see edited answer. Replace `nPoints` and `currentValue` based on your simulation.

Comment: I don't understand why script is separated from function. Could you explain, please? Also, will this function draw trajectory in real time? Am I correct that this function will draw trajectory only after if it get all the points?

Comment: The script is separate from the function, because you need to retain the handle for `animatedline`. In your original code, you were creating a new `animatedline` object at every function call. This should draw the trajectory in real-time, it does not need all points.

Comment: I'm sorry for such a stupid question but how can I implement separate function and script in my Simulink model ? I have only one block which leads to MATLAB function `trajectory(u)`  https://i.imgur.com/iaieOke.png

Comment: See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-an-example-model-that-uses-a-matlab-function-block.html#f6-143734),